# React render context / context.router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How would I pass the context of the current component into a new component when using `React.render` for the second component?

I have component A, which is a child of `App`, rendered into the document.

I cannot use the normal nested rendering process to render component B into component A. Component A is a third-party React component and I need to modify its DOM structure.

I'm using jQuery to add an empty div into component A and then render component B into the empty div, i.e.:

```
React.render(componentB, jqueryDOMNode);
```

This works fine, except that component B is then rendered outside React Router which wraps `App`. The problem then becomes React Router requires `context.router` but component B does not receive the router in its context, i.e.

```
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },
```

does not work in component B.

I've tried passing component A's context to component B via props and also using a wrapper component with `childContextTypes` and `getChildContext` to no avail:

```
var ComponentBWrapper = React.createFactory(React.createClass({    
  childContextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },

  getChildContext: function() {
    return {router: this.props.context.router};
  },

  render: function() {
    return ComponentB(_.omit(this.props, 'context'));
  }
}));
```

Thoughts?

Comment: If this is true: "Component A is a third-party React component and I need to modify its DOM structure", then you are intensely violating the core concept of React's "you know yourself, and you can instruct your children, and everything else is not yours to modify", and you should be seriously reconsidering what you're actually trying to do. If you need to work with "the DOM", you are abusing, not using, React. Don't use jQuery to add things into React components, that way lies madness.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your thoughts, but delivering the needed feature is critical for our product.

Comment: those needs do not carry over into giving good advice - anyone else finding this question is going to need to hear "this is really not how to use React, and if you're doing React this way, you're really doing React wrong". But maybe someone else will be willing to delve into what you could do and furnish you with an answer yet.

Comment: This is really asking for troubles. Try to come up with a non hacky way to solve your problem (you didn't explain why you had these constraints)